# __builtin_operator_new recursion on call

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator

I am currently studying memory handling and experiencing an issue. When I attempt to utilize `__builtin_operator_new` I encounter recursion leading to a STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW error:

```
Exception 0xc00000fd encountered at address 0x7ff698ff100e
```

What could be causing this problem?

From the clang [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-operator-new-and-builtin-operator-delete), it is evident that these operators should operate similarly to the standard operators new and delete. Below is a sample code that demonstrates the issue:

```cpp
class tester {
  public:
    explicit tester( int value ) : m_value( value ) { }

    [[nodiscard]] auto value( ) const -> int {
        return m_value;
    }

  private:
    int m_value { };
};

#include <memory>

[[nodiscard]] auto operator new ( const std::size_t __sz ) -> void * {
    return ::__builtin_operator_new( __sz );
}

auto operator delete ( void *__ptr ) noexcept -> void {
    return ::__builtin_operator_delete( __ptr );
}

extern "C" {
    auto start( ) -> int {
        const auto test = std::make_unique< tester >( 99 );

        const auto value = test->value( );
        ( void ) value;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zE834sYM5)

Also the flags that I use:
`-fno-exceptions;-nostdlib;-Wl,-e,start`

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did your debugger show you for the stack frames of the infinite recursion?

Comment: Did you not notice that it calls the `operator new` that you defined (which replaced the regular global allocation function)? This is also exactly what happens if you call `::operator new`.

Comment: On a side note, identifiers with two consecutive underscores are reserved for the implementation, and you should not define any. There are plenty of other names to choose from.

Comment: I would just forward to `malloc`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat And what about starting the lifetime of objects in that case?

Comment: @PepijnKramer `operator new`, as opposed to `new`, is just a memory allocating function. It doesn't start any lifetime (and doesn't need to), other than the implicit C++20 lifetime stuff. Any constructors are called by `new`-expression calling the `operator new`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I missed that, thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll note that `__builtin_operator_new` is a clang extension, and is not part of the C++ standard. The clang documentation says: "A call to `__builtin_operator_new(args)` is exactly the same as a call to `::operator new(args)`, except [...] and that the call is required to resolve to a replaceable global allocation function." I would interpret this to mean that `__builtin_operator_new` is not required to resolve to a replaceable global allocation function, but that it may -- in your case, it looks like it is resolving to the global allocation function that you've defined. When it resolves to the global allocation function, and when it doesn't, probably depends on various optimizations, and whether the declaration of the global allocation function is visible or not.

I might add that the `nostdlib` option could mean that the standard `operator new` isn't even available, and that the only one present is the one you've defined.